# Display the date with Emacs editor

Tags: emacs, text-editor, fish

I'm trying to configure `Today is 20/11/2016` with Emacs editor. I think the command `date` is located in `\bin`. Therefore, with the editor I wrote what is in the following image :

[image]

I know it should be straighforward, but I am a beginner (so it's not). Could anyone be able to tell me what do I have to do to fix this? I know with bash shell, I should use `$(date +%D)` to obtain the date. However, as I use fish shell, I don't even know what it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste this in the editor

```
 C-u M-! date
```

`M-! date` is shell command for date and `C-u` is prefix to put its output in current buffer.

Another method,

add the following to your ~/.emacs:

```
 (display-time-mode 1)
```

Ref : https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DisplayTime

Comment: I need a bit more explanation please.  What could replace `$(date)` in fish shell

Comment: @Sandra I have edited my answer and added what you are looking for. hopefully this helps.